# My applications do not proceed when I leave my computer

Tags: suspend, power-management, idle

I have written a C++ application which displays and renders a lot of graphical frames into a video. When I am watching my PC, it works quickly. But when I come back to my PC tomorrow, I realize that a very short portion of rendering has been proceeded. I assume that Ubuntu is going to sleep/suspend mode when I leave it as it is. It is interesting that the current setting says do not suspend.

As my PC has no battery related issue, how can entirely disable sleep and suspend?

```
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

[image: Power management: screenshot]

Comment: Can you answer a couple of questions?  Is this a desktop or a laptop?  Is your application running from a GUI login or one of the console logins such as Alt-Ctrl-F1 or Alt-Ctrl-F2?

Comment: @L.D.James, This is a normal ubuntu for desktop installed on a desktop PC. I run my ubuntu via the default GUI.

Comment: Maybe your application stops rendering when the screen is locked. If so, you could use caffeine to keep Ubuntu awake/unlocked. `sudo apt install caffeine` (and activate it of course).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally realized that I should prevent my computer from locking rather than sleep, screen saver, etc.